# How to delete entry from indented argument from list?

Tags: indentation, normal-mode

Let's say with the cursor I'm on `b` in

```
def f(a=1,
      b=2,
      c=3,
      e=4
      )
```

and we want to delete the whole argument including the line break, so that we get

```
def f(a=1,
      c=3,
      e=4
      )
```

but without deleting the preceding character (i.e. it should also be applicable to deleting `a...`) What is the shortest way to do so?

I'm asking because in non-vim texteditors you could do so by selecting the whole line using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd> and then deleting the selection using <kbd>del</kbd>, and so far I have not found an efficient way to do so in vim, the best I could come up with is using visual mode: <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>

---

You can also imagine a similar situation with something like

```
y = a * xa + \
    b * xb + \
    c * xc
```

Comment: If you're writing a lot of python, I suggest setting up black+ale and letting it autoformat on save. It saves me the trouble of doing it manually; I would just press `D` on the `a` character and then save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do, `DJx`

```
D -> delete rest of the line
J -> join the next line
x -> delete the space added by join
```

Comment: Just a note that on the other lines, you don't need `x`

Answer (score 2):

> the best I could come up with is using visual mode: v, j, h, d

`h` is needed, because you've `set selection=inclusive` (this is default). To make the selection behave like in a majority of other text editors use `set selection=exclusive`.

Next, if you want `shift+arrow` to start the selection you should `set keymodel=startsel`.

Also, "delete" normally works the same way as `x`, so having set the two options above you should be able to do "shift+down+delete" to do the job.

So, as you see, the whole difference is due to the "unusual" default settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see how you can use these commands for my purpose: In each case the whole line (including the preceding characters) is deleted. I am however looking to delete everything from `b` to the character before `c` in this example - is that possible with these commands?

Comment: @flawr If you want to make "shift+down+del" work then `set selection=exclusive` and `set keymodel=startsel`